# Powershell scripting clean up activity

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a scenario here, i am working on files clean up activity.

I have folders and withing the folder i have excel and pdf files. I want to retain the last two modified files and delete all other files.

Please help me writing the script.

Regards
NKS

Comment: Questions asking for help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1):

To do something with all but the two most recently modified files can be done with a sort and then skipping two (broken over lines for ease of reading):

```
dir *.doc |
  sort LastWriteTimeUtc -desc |
  select -skip 2 |
  # Do something like remove-item
```

(Using UTC to avoid problems when entering/leaving DST.)